# Harnessing molecule vibration energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy-conservation, vacuum, perpetual-motion

Disclaimer: I am learning physics for fun, please dont kill me but explain where I am wrong.

As I understand all molecules have a lowest energy state in which they posses some amount of momentum even in complete vaccum. 
Can we transfer this minimum momentum into useful energy source?
I know that if molecules have energy high enough for chemical reaction to occur then we can harvest that molecules energy with ease.

Edit: I imagine vibrating molecule of helium at 0K hitting some part that moves or maybe generates pressure you know some kind of momentum.
I mean it has some momentum so it can give it to something else right?

I am not sure what tags to add

Edit: answered i think but here is a very interesting conversation i found on the topic:
www.researchgate.net/post/Is_extraction_of_Zero_point_energy_a_real_phenomenon
Maybe big bang is a violation of 2nd law

Comment: If these objects were in their "lowest energy state", then what state are they in after you have transferred the momentum "into useful energy source"?

Comment: If the molecules were in thermal equilibrium at 0 Kelvin, then 100% of them would be in the ground state.  Vibrational energy in excited states can facilitate some reactions, but only under disequilibrium conditions.  Lasers, for example, require population inversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine your He atom is vibrating at $0K$. You wonder what happens if it hits something. However, the "something" must also be vibrating, so perhaps the energy transfer goes the other way and the He atom ends up vibrating **more** after the interaction...

Or do you think the "something" could be not vibrating?

Remember how vibrational energy at microscopic scale is what we call *heat* at our scale. So what you are imagining is that the He atom at $0K$ is hitting something *colder* than itself. But the helium is already at $0K$ so how can anything be colder?

So the answer is that you *can* get energy out of atomic vibrations, so long as the energy is flowing from a hot thing to a colder thing. Once everything is at absolute zero, no more heat will flow.

Comment: Such vivid and simple explanation, wow you are good at this

Comment: I'm sorry the downvoter didn't like my answer (perhaps explain why? - just so I can aspire to rise to your required standard the next time...).

Comment: @newUser Thanks for your comments - I'm glad the answer was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

As you state yourself, this is the *minimum* energy it can have. As in: there is no lower energy possible. If you extracted that energy, what energy would the molecule still have? There are, by definition, no lower states to exist in for the molecule, hence the energy cannot be transferred anywhere.

Comment: I guess they would be in the same state. I know energy cant appear out of thin air but isn't it already happening? I know that Heisenbergs principle dictates that every molecule has some energy or is in infinite space but where really that energy comes from?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's possible to make any use of the energy. (I also learning physics for fun. So I'm just gonna give my understanding on this topic)  I think that even if we transfer the energy, there would be so little that it wouldn't be of any use. 
It would also be very difficult to get the energy, because if we did, then it would be in its ground state (absolute zero), and so far this is impossible, so we may not even be able to extract the small amount of energy left.

Comment: But if we get that energy we wont deplete it from this molecule it must be like refilled from somwhere else otherwise conservation of energy would break i think

Answer (score 0):

IF all atoms are at the minimum energy state, would this not be a zero-point energy field or a condensate?

The random motion corresponding to this zero-point energy never vanishes as a consequence of the uncertainty principle"  (which is one reason that helium does not freeze)....

Now you could use the zero point energy as an energy source, but you have to combine it with a heat source.  This would be the thermoelectric effect.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about transferring molecular momenta into energy you are correct. This thing is known as heat energy and heat energy can be transferred according to the laws of thermodynamics.

Now coming back to your question,

You are telling you want to harness energy from **He** molecules at zero K which are having some momentum. I don't know but if you have learnt about [gas laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws) you will see that a gas can't exert pressure at $0$ kelvins as it has no kinetic energy.
And I'd say that energy can't be harnessed at $0$ kelvins as theoretically all molecular movements cease to exist. Above it there is always some ***K.E*** associated with a molecule, so theoretically you can continue to harness energy until you reduce the molecule's energy to nothing.

Comment: "at 0 kelvins as theoretically all molecular movements cease to exist" - that's what i am trying to wrap my head about because quantum mechanics says that theres always some molecular movement in a confined space no matter temperature